# How do I do an elementwise sum of the current element and next three row elements (in column 0) using array operations not a for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, elementwise-operations

> I am trying to do an operation relative to the location of the element
> during an elementwise numpy operation.  I cannot figure out how access
> the current location in order to sum it with the next three elements.
> I have included a sample array as well as a sample solution I am
> trying to achieve.  Since the real array is over 1MM rows a for loop
> would be too slow.  Thank you!

```
import numpy as np

k = np.random.rand(10,1)*10
k.astype(int)
```

[image: sample goal solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`np.convolve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html#numpy-convolve):

```py
N = 3
x = np.convolve(k.ravel(), np.ones(N, dtype=int), "full")[N - 1 :].reshape(-1, 1)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```py
[[17]
 [14]
 [ 5]
 [14]
 [14]
 [15]
 [11]
 [14]
 [13]
 [ 8]]
```

---

The input array was:

```py
[[8]
 [9]
 [0]
 [5]
 [0]
 [9]
 [5]
 [1]
 [5]
 [8]]
```